# Quantifying "admitting no positive scalar curvature metrics"

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request

Given $\epsilon\geq 0$, are there manifolds $M$ such that for every metric $g$ on $M$, there is some point $x\in M$ such that $R_g(x)\leq \epsilon$? For the case of $\epsilon =0$, this is the question of which manifolds admit no positive scalar curvature metrics, for which the torus is a classic example. However, I'm really interested in the $\epsilon>0$ case, and I'm wondering if such things are studied. In other words, I'm looking for manifolds $M$ in which the following cannot hold. For any $\epsilon>0$, there is a metric $g_\epsilon$ on $M$ such that $-\epsilon<R_{g_\epsilon}$.

Conversely, perhaps the question for $\epsilon>0$ is not well-posed, as I may be able to "average out" points of negative scalar curvature locally and increase the scalar curvature at a point. Either way, I'm interested in hearing any inputs.

Comment: By Gauss-Bonnet, any metric on a closed surface of genus $g \geqslant 2$ has this property for the reason that the Gauss curvature (which is half the scalar curvature) has to be negative somewhere (the total scalar curvature is negative).

Comment: Do you know if Gauss-Bonnet implies that every metric on a genius $\geq 2$ surface must be strictly bounded away from $0$ (a constant uniform w.r.t any metric on the surface)?

Comment: You can prescribe any metric on a small neighbourhood, with scalar curvature as large as you want, and then complete it with a partition of unity argument. So I guess the answer to your comment is "no" (if I understand it well)

Comment: Because scaling a metric inversely scales curvature,  non-zero curvature bounds are often studied relative to some other global bounds.  E.g., $R_g(x)\leq \epsilon$ and bounds on diameter, max curvature, min injectivity radius, etc.